# how to customize android calender view with highlight today date

Tags: android

hi i am working on android and my project requirement need android calender view with highlighted today date and what ever user selected date can pick and no limit for date range and i am excepted output like a below screen shot and i have try some sample code but,doesn't work can you any sample api or customize calender view with highlighted today date.

[image]

can you help me how to do this like above screen shot and screen shot taken from google calender app now available on playshop.

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand some parts but I think you mean you want to make a custom calendar right?
Using grid view, a calendar can be implemented easily.

Try [API Guide on Grid View](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) to get some information on how a grid view works.

You may want to extend this grid view by loading an array list on to the grid view adapter.

Comment: Maybe this is what you want. It has unlimited date range with a few bugs.[Calendar Sample](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your request correctly, what you want is [android-times-square](https://github.com/square/android-times-square). They advertise it as

> Standalone Android widget for picking a single date from a calendar view.

Comment: i have used this but i need with out limit date ranges how to do this on android time square calender view?

Comment: You should improve your question by telling exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: i need just differ today date like round date or bold text with default calender (infinite limit date range like 1900 to 2099)?

Comment: if i am using android times square calender need library project but,i want to with out any reference project?